# Select Users that are not blocked - SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table **users**:

- **id**
- **name**

And another table **blocked_users**:

- **user_id**
- **user_blocked_id**

When a user blocks another, the add their id to the **blocked_users.user_id** and the user they block in **blocked_users.user_blocked_id**.

I want to select all the users from **users** table where my **user.id** does not exits neither in **blocked_users.user_id** (Users that I have blocked) nor **blocked_users.user_block_id** (Someone else has blocked me). So none of them can see other's information.

```
SELECT        a.*
FROM          users a
LEFT JOIN     blocked_users b
ON            b.user_id = a.id
AND           b.user_blocked_id = a.id
WHERE NOT     b.user_id = '$id'
AND NOT       b.user_blocked_id = '$id';
```

Im Stuck on the query!

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: If you're using PHP, you should add that tag to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `not exists`:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from blocked_users bu
                  where bu.user_id = u.id and bu.user_blocked_id = ?
                 ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from blocked_users bu
                  where bu.user_blocked_id = u.id and bu.user_id = ?
                 );
```

Note the use of `?`.  This is for passing in parameters into the query.  This is much better than munging the query with a string value.

Comment: Parameterized queries exist in native SQL ?

Comment: @GangaiJohann . . . Pretty much any database that lets applications talk to it supports parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select **all** of the users from **users** table, then use the following code:

```
select u.*
  from users u
 where not exists (select 1
                     from blocked_users bu
                    where bu.user_id = u.id) 
   and not exists (select 1
                     from blocked_users bu
                    where bu.user_blocked_id = u.id);
```